# When I load the track in garage band, I can hear it, but I can't see it!

Tags: audio, radio

My friends and I do a radio show and we use Garageband to record our individual tracks.  Then they get uploaded to our site, where I download them and drag the entire file into Garageband.  Voila! Radio Show! Right? Wrong!

Every time, and only with 1 of the 2 performers, when I load the track I can hear him, but I can't see him.  His wave form doesn't appear.  Then, like magic, it suddenly appears...

What am I doing to cause/deserve this?

Comment: Is it only the wave form that is missing, or is it the entire audio region?

Answer (score 5):

Garageband has to do a fair bit of processing in order to display the waveform. In order to minimise wasted time for the performers, it allows you to hear this waveform straight away, while doing the waveform processing in the background.

So really, you are seeing symptoms of the app developers trying to be helpful by letting you hear the music before it is actually ready to be processed.

Comment: This is helpful as I am having the same issue. Only it hasn't appeared yet. How long does it take?